# Can I use different wire gauges in quick disconnect and from panel?

Tags: electrical, mini-split

Quick disconnect kit came pre installed with 10 gauge wire.

The split AC unit calls for a 20 amp double pole (2 hots). So that sounds like 12 gauge.

I realize it’s probably okay to do 10 gauge for the whole run, but it’ll be more expensive and cumbersome.

Can my quick disconnect keep its 10 gauge to the condenser, and from the panel to quick disconnect run 12 gauge from the 20 amp breaker? I wouldn’t be asking if the whip from the quick disconnect didn’t come with it all nice and tidy and ready to go.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### That's fine

There is nothing wrong with having larger wire than necessary for part of a run; most people don't upsize willy-nilly due to the cost of copper, but since you're getting a prefabricated assembly, this isn't an issue.

Comment: And it's 10AWG so they can make them all the same and have them support both 20A and 30A units.  Cheaper than making two different ones.